# How to populate a nested generic list with struts2 OGNL?

Tags: java, struts2, type-conversion, ognl

I am trying to populate an Action property from a JSP page. The action property is of the following class:

```
public class SearchResult<T> {
  private List<T> records;
  // getters/setters as needed
}
```

In the action, the type of the generic is specified.

```
private SearchResult<MyObject> searchResult;
// getters/setters as needed
```

I am trying to submit the following to the action, but the `records` list ends up either empty or filled with nulls (depending how many records I try to populate).

```
&searchResult.records[0].prop1.propA=value1
&searchResult.records[0].prop1.propB=value2
&searchResult.records[1].prop1.propA=value3
&searchResult.records[1].prop1.propB=value4
```

Is there a different OGNL syntax I should be using or some other trick?

Comment: generics works well in S2.what kind of object `MyObject` is?

Comment: Yes, if I change the Action property to the generic list and pass in `&records[0].prop1.propA=value1` it works. However, it doesn't work for me when the generic list is nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not seeing any responses to this question, I'd say Struts2 doesn't support nested generic lists.